# validation rules on multiple fields

Tags: validation-rule

I have written this simple validation rule that will throw an error when the user enters less than 2 characters in Name and Responsibilities fields.

```
LEN(Name)<2 && 
LEN(Responsibilities__c)<2
```

But this isn't working . If I use either of those then the error is showing up but when I'm combining both the record is being saved even if I enter less than two characters in either of the fields.

Comment: whats you actual requirement? both Name and Responsibilities__c must be greater than 2 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule from `&&` to `||`, so both Name and Responsibilities__c must be at least 2 Characters.

```
LEN(Name)<2 || 
LEN(Responsibilities__c)<2
```

Also, verify in case you need to do `BLANK` check before checking the length

Comment: Aah! You beat me to it.